# JavaScript tool for placing and scaling images

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, image-editing

I was wondering if there are any JavaScript tools out there with which you can let the user place and scale one or multiple images on a canvas for example.  I know there are tools like [cropperjs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs), [cropper](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper) or [Croppie](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/) for image cropping - but I was wondering if something similar exists for letting the user scale, position and rotate one or multiple images.

I am having a tough time googling this since all I find are just general instructions on how to scale and rotate images with JavaScript and/or HTML5 etc.

The background is that I want the user to be able to upload a file and then place other images on top of his uploaded image freely (those would be transparent PNGs). That information would then be sent to the server and the images would be combined into one.

(If no such tool exists yet then I would have to code it myself of course, though I really thought there ought to be something.)

Comment: See this demo for fabricjs: http://fabricjs.com/bounding-rectangle

Answer (score 0):

There is one called DarkroomJS (if you havent already checked this one out). You can fork the repo. Last commit was around a year ago however.

Comment: Thanks, but `Fabric.js` (as suggested by @Giladd), which DarkroomJS uses, seems to be the best thing for the job I require.